# C/ min and max of a little field

Tags: c, int, max, min

My Program doesnt work.
I want to have the max and min values.
Whats the mistake?
Thx to all ;)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 5
int main()
{
    int wert[N],i,min,max;
    printf("Bitte geben Sie 5 Zahlen ein! \n");
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        scanf("%i",&wert[i]);//Eingabe der Werte
        printf("Wiederholung: \n");
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        printf("\n %i \n",wert[i]);//Aushabe der Werte
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        if (wert[i]<min)
        wert[i]=min;
        else if (wert[i]>max)
        wert[i]=max;
    printf("Maximalwert: %i",max);
    printf("Minimalwert: %i",min);
    return 0;
```

Comment: Why `c#` tag then? It looks irrelevant

Comment: Define "doesn't work". It doesn't compile? It crashes? It works but gives you a different outcome to the one you expected?

Comment: @starsplusplus the program compiles and works. but the min and max values are false. Thats the only problem. Ive solved the problem with the solution from Sakthi Kumar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
min = max = wert[0];
for(i=1;i<N;i++)
        if (wert[i]<min)
        min = wert[i];//<--wert[i]=min;
        else if (wert[i]>max)
        max = wert[i];//<--wert[i]=max;
```

Apart from initialization, the values are assigned reverse

Answer (score 8):

You did not initialise `min`, `max`.

```
#include <limits.h>

int min = INT_MAX;
int max = 0;
```

Comment: @user3336852 `limits.h` is not a library, but a header containing the min/max values for your integers. If you are on a standard two-s complement CPU then you can use `((unsigned int)~0) >> 1` instead of `INT_MAX`, but using the macro from `limits.h` is more portable and good coding practice.

Comment: There are a few problems with this code (`main` is missing a closing brace for a start) and I think it would be more helpful to get the OP to go through their compile errors than to provide them straight-out with an answer.